# Displaying Images vertically in frontend using codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

Hi i am using codeigniter framework and i have implemented backend functionality part to upload images for portfolio section it is working fine.But while displaying those images in frontend it is displaying in horizontal manner but the images should display in vertical order.Here is my code.

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
    $data['records2'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_portfolio();
    $data['mainpage'] = "portfolio";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_portfolio()
{
    $this->db->Select('portfolio.*');
    $this->db->From('portfolio');
    $this->db->where(array('portfolio.status'=>1));
    $q=$this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)      
    {       
        return $q->result();
     }
        else
        {
    return false;
  }
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
                <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>
                <div class="portfolioimages">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/portfolioimages/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" alt="portfolioimages" class="portfoliomage1"/>                                 
                </div>                  
                <?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Comment: can you provide css of classes portfolioimages and portfoliomage1

Comment: .portfolioimages {
    margin-top: 77px;
    margin-left: 55px;
}   There is no css for portfoliomage1

Comment: can you add add display:block css to portfolioimages

Comment: no it is not working it is displaying the images horizontally only.In a row i need to display only 3 images

Comment: anyone can help me this

Comment: Codeigniter is a backend framework. For front-end frameworks, consider Bootstrap or similar. With Bootstrap you can do exactly what you're after very easily.

Comment: Do you have any CSS for the class `portfolioimages` ?